# Expected primary expression

Tags: contract-development

Hello friends i have error at my code can i have some help please

code :

```
pragma solidity 0.4.8;

/* The token is used as a voting shares */
contract token { mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;  }

/* The democracy contract itself */
contract Democracy {

/* Contract Variables and events */
uint public minimumQuorum;
uint public debatingPeriodInMinutes;
Proposal[] public proposals;
uint public numProposals;
token public sharesTokenAddress;

event ProposalAdded(uint proposalID, address recipient, uint amount, string description);
event Voted(uint proposalID, bool position, address voter);
event ProposalTallied(uint proposalID, int result, uint quorum, bool active);

struct Proposal {
    address recipient;
    uint amount;
    string description;
    uint votingDeadline;
    bool openToVote;
    bool proposalPassed;
    uint numberOfVotes;
    bytes32 proposalHash;
    Vote[] votes;
    mapping (address => bool) voted;
}

struct Vote {
    bool inSupport;
    address voter;
}

/* modifier that allows only shareholders to vote and create new proposals */
modifier onlyShareholders {
    if (sharesTokenAddress.balanceOf(msg.sender) == 0) throw;
    _;
}

/* First time setup */
function Democracy(token sharesAddress, uint minimumSharesForVoting, uint minutesForDebate) {
    sharesTokenAddress = token(sharesAddress);
    if (minimumSharesForVoting == 0 ) minimumSharesForVoting = 1;
    minimumQuorum = minimumSharesForVoting;
    debatingPeriodInMinutes = minutesForDebate;
}

/* Function to create a new proposal */
function newProposal(address beneficiary, uint etherAmount, string JobDescription, bytes transactionBytecode) onlyShareholders returns (uint proposalID) {
    proposalID = proposals.length++;
    Proposal p = proposals[proposalID];
    p.recipient = beneficiary;
    p.amount = etherAmount;
    p.description = JobDescription;
    p.proposalHash = sha3(beneficiary, etherAmount, transactionBytecode);
    p.votingDeadline = now + debatingPeriodInMinutes * 1 minutes;
    p.openToVote = true;
    p.proposalPassed = false;
    p.numberOfVotes = 0;
    ProposalAdded(proposalID, beneficiary, etherAmount, JobDescription);
    numProposals = proposalID+1;
}

/* function to check if a proposal code matches */
function checkProposalCode(uint proposalNumber, address beneficiary, uint etherAmount, bytes transactionBytecode) constant returns (bool codeChecksOut) {
    Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
    return p.proposalHash == sha3(beneficiary, etherAmount, transactionBytecode);
}

/* */
function vote(uint proposalNumber, bool supportsProposal) onlyShareholders returns (uint voteID){
    Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
    if (p.voted[msg.sender] == true) throw;

    voteID = p.votes.length++;
    p.votes[voteID] = Vote({inSupport: supportsProposal, voter: msg.sender});
    p.voted[msg.sender] = true;
    p.numberOfVotes = voteID +1;
    Voted(proposalNumber,  supportsProposal, msg.sender);
}

function executeProposal(uint proposalNumber, bytes transactionBytecode) returns (int result) {
    Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
    /* Check if the proposal can be executed */
    if (now < p.votingDeadline  /* has the voting deadline arrived? */ 
        || !p.openToVote        /* has it been already executed? */
        ||  p.proposalHash != sha3(p.recipient, p.amount, transactionBytecode)) /* Does the transaction code match the proposal? */
        throw;

    /* tally the votes */
    uint quorum = 0;
    uint yea = 0; 
    uint nay = 0;

    for (uint i = 0; i <  p.votes.length; ++i) {
        Vote v = p.votes[i];
        uint voteWeight = sharesTokenAddress.balanceOf(v.voter);
```

Error: 
[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you copied and pasted this from elsewhere? If so, you're missing the closing parentheses to the final `for` loop, final function, and the contract itself...

```
       for (uint i = 0; i <  p.votes.length; ++i) {
            Vote v = p.votes[i];
            uint voteWeight = sharesTokenAddress.balanceOf(v.voter); 
        } <---
    } <---
}  <---
```

I also had to update the compiler version to `pragma solidity 0.4.10;`.

Comment: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.4.8+commit.60cc1668.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity 0.4.10;
^---------------------^